# Unable to assign a value to the dynamic sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a dynamic sql query to execute based on the input I receive from the user and display the details on the click of a button. Below is the function that gets called when the button is clicked.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 cn.Open();
 st = "Select * from Info where Roll_no=" + textBox1.Text; 
 cmd = new SqlCommand(st,cn);
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 if(dr.Read())
 {
  textBox2.Text = dr.GetString(1);
  textBox3.Text = dr.GetString(2).ToString();
  textBox4.Text = dr.GetString(3).ToString();
  textBox5.Text = dr.GetString(4).ToString();
  textBox6.Text = dr.GetString(5);
  textBox1.Focus();
  button3.Enabled = true;
  button4.Enabled = true;
 }
 else
 {
  MessageBox.Show("No Such record exists");
  textBox1.Clear();
  textBox1.Focus();
  button3.Enabled = false;
  button4.Enabled = false;
 }
 dr.Close();
 cn.Close();
}
```

The error is at the construction of sql query. Getting the error ***An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.***
Textbox1.Text returns the roll no what the user has typed and Roll_no is of type int.

Comment: What is `textBox1.Text`? What is the type of `Roll_no`? By the way, [George Boole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole) could really upset if he saw your `dr.Read() == true` part. Just `if(dr.Read())` will be enough.

Comment: type of roll_no is int

Comment: @SonerGönül Wish I could give you a +1 for the George Boole reference.

Comment: Why am I getting this error

Answer (score 0):

type your query like: "Select * from Info where Roll_no = '" + textBox1.Text+'" ;";
Hope it helps.